# What is system-python that are required by efs utils?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rpm

I need to install amazon-efs-utils on a custom AMI instance. One of the dependency for efs-utils is python2.7 which my environment had came pre-installed (based on [pkg.org](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/okey-x86_64/amazon-efs-utils-1.7-1.el7.noarch.rpm.html)). I have checked that python is in the path

When I do `python --version`, it returns `Python 2.7.5`

but when I ran `rpm -ivh amazon-efs-utils-1.7-1.el7.noarch.rpm`,

It returned `error:Failed Dependencies: system-python is needed by amazon-efs-utils-1.7-1.el7.noarch.rpm`

What is this `system-python` dependency if it is not python 2.7?

I am working in a restricted internet network hence using yum to search for mirror is not possible and amazon-efs-utils does not come installed in the AMI that I am working on

Comment: Is that AMI based on amazon linux 1?

Comment: @Marcin Yes it is

Comment: @superbrain I did, It didn't lead to anywhere relating to rpm throwing this error

Comment: Ok. I thought [this](https://superuser.com/a/1214047) might help explain what it is. So that's about a different system-python?

Comment: You can force rpm installation if you think you have all dependencies as shown [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/force-v-s-nodeps-rpm-command-options-to-install-or-uninstall-a-package/)

Comment: RPM doesn't check "is Python 2.7 available", it checks for "is the `system-python` package installed". You can tell it yes by other means, but the simplest by far is to actually install `system-python`.

Answer (score 0):

The `system-python` is just python:

```
  dependency: system-python
   provider: python27.x86_64 2.7.18-1.137.amzn1
```

Full dependencies of `amazon-efs-utils` are

```
      sudo yum deplist  amazon-efs-utils
      Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
      package: amazon-efs-utils.noarch 1.26-3.amzn1
      dependency: /bin/sh
       provider: bash.x86_64 4.2.46-34.43.amzn1
      dependency: /sbin/chkconfig
       provider: chkconfig.x86_64 1.3.49.3-2.14.amzn1
      dependency: /sbin/service
       provider: initscripts.x86_64 9.03.58-1.40.amzn1
      dependency: /usr/bin/python2.7
       provider: python27.x86_64 2.7.18-1.137.amzn1
      dependency: config(amazon-efs-utils) = 1.26-3.amzn1
       provider: amazon-efs-utils.noarch 1.26-3.amzn1
      dependency: nfs-utils
       provider: nfs-utils.x86_64 1:1.3.0-0.21.amzn1
      dependency: openssl >= 1.0.2
       provider: openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.151.amzn1
       provider: openssl.i686 1:1.0.2k-16.151.amzn1
      dependency: stunnel >= 4.56
       provider: stunnel.x86_64 4.56-4.13.amzn1
      dependency: system-python
       provider: python27.x86_64 2.7.18-1.137.amzn1
      dependency: util-linux
       provider: util-linux.x86_64 2.23.2-59.29.amzn1
       provider: util-linux.i686 2.23.2-59.29.amzn1
      dependency: which
       provider: which.x86_64 2.19-6.10.amzn1
```

Comment: I can't use `yum install` because the environment restricts outbound connection. I am creating an offline local yum repo however the `system-python` dependency is throwing it off

Comment: @NitroReload I see. Let me check if there is something else that can be done.

Comment: @NitroReload I updated answer with dependencies required.